# Error 'argument "param" is missing, with no default' - optim() function in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, data-science, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use Pythagoras’ theorem to calculate the minimum value of time by creating functions in R that output T and (dT/dX1) as a function of X1, and use the `optim()` to numerically find the value of X1 that minimises T.

```
Time_1 <- function(param){((sqrt(param^2 + 225))/10) + ((sqrt(((25-param)^2) + 100))/2)} #Function to define T

D_Time <- function(param){(param / (10*(sqrt(param ^ 2 + 225)))) +
((param- 25) / (2*sqrt((25 - param) ^ 2 + 100)))} #Function to define (dT/dX1)

start_guess <- 1#start value
mle_param <- optim(par=start_guess, fn = Time_1(),gr = D_Time(), method = 'Brent')
Error in D_Time() : argument "param" is missing, with no default
```

I know something wrong with the fn=?, gr=?, but don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by user 'jogo' replace `fn` and `gr` parameters with the name of respective functions without the parenthesis.

Moreover, as you already figured out, the `Brent` method needs the `lower` and `upper` parameters to be filled in:

> lower, upper ... , or bounds in which to search for method "Brent"

```
mle_param <- optim(par = start_guess,
                   fn = Time_1,
                   gr = D_Time,
                   method = 'Brent',
                   lower = 1,
                   upper = 25)
```